# Facebook iOS SDK - Log in without the LoginButton (Programmatically)

Tags: ios, facebook, xamarin, facebook-login

Is it possibly to log-in and -out without the use of the LoginButton - and how ?

I have currently been using this example:

https://components.xamarin.com/gettingstarted/facebookios

Since it is for a Xamarin project, and it is working besides i would like to use my own buttons and not the Facebook one. 
-Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the Facebook developer site they recommend to send events to the login button. Find more details [here](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/ios/advanced), in the

> Custom Login Button

section.

Comment: Thanks for the answer - I solved it with a mix of a custom button and hiding the button when not needed. But still didn't find a way to do it programmatically.